# LinkedIn share API issue

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am making an app in order to post an image to LinkedIn.

The problem is that it's not working for images.
I use my uploaded image URL in `submitted-image-url` in order to post my image with a caption but unfortunately, it just uses a thumbnail of my image.

What can I do to post my image? By the way, I use PHP.

Comment: *_If you can give me a code_*, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: what is the response of the api

Comment: How can I give you the code ?

Comment: By the way the response of the api is 200 ok and it will send the post properly but the image is not in right form and it is like a tumbnail from url not like a post with image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, as of May, 2020, LinkedIn ***only*** supports the `url` parameter in its share URL.  So, you'll have to share the image by making it a linkable file and then share the URL to the file, like so..

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check us out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]